# How to track traffic flows to each IP on home network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt, snmp

first-timer here.  I will try to explain this as clearly as possible, as I'm not an engineer or anything.

My Router: ASUS RT-AC87U - DD-WRT firmware installed, SNMP enabled.

Topology: 
I have two switches off the router.
behind switch 1: 2 W8 Desktops 
behind switch 2: TV, Roku, Xbox.

On wireless:
2 Rokus, 4 iPhones, W8 laptop, chromebook, 2 Kindles

What I'm looking to do:
I would like to be able to see traffic data to each individual IP I choose, particularly the rate at which it's flowing. Mostly because there are some devices sucking large amounts of data and I want to understand what they are, where they are receiving the data from and at what rate. And partly because I'm a geek and granular data is just something I prefer.

I installed PRTG and put an SNMP trap on my router, but the data isn't very useful to me. It put probes on there like eth0, vlan1, vlan2, br0 etc. 
I tested with my machine when no other device in the house was streaming. What I saw was about 30K kbps, on eth0 and about half of that on vlan1. I'm sure there's an explanation for this that I don't understand, but at the end of the day - I stil can't get what I need when two different traps are displaying 2 different speeds for only 1 device. Plus the wireless devices are mostly what I'm interested in.

Is there a way I can configure the traps so it's 1:1? Will it require scripting? Do I need another solution besides PRTG? Is any of this even possible on a home router?

I will thank you all in advance for any insight/solutions you can provide, and I'll apologize as well if this is a redundant question that I couldn't find the thread to.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DD-WRT comes with rflow, which is designed for exactly what you're asking.
Check out their wiki here: https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Network_traffic_analysis_with_netflow_and_ntop

Comment: So that article talks about a standalone server/machine to tackle that. I do have another tower laying around - are there any minimum specs it should have to keep up with the logging/monitoring?

Comment: It doesn't need to be standalone - it can be one of your existing systems as long as it is always-on and has a predictable IP (static, DHCP reserved, etc)... No data will be logged if the target host is unavailable.